# Prove that $X_n \to X$ in $L^1$ if and only if $E(X_n1_{A}) \to E(X1_{A})$ uniformly on $A \in \mathcal{F}$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, lp-spaces

This is a probability exercise from the Karr's book called "Probability".

> Prove that $X_n \overset{L^1}{\rightarrow} X$ if and only if
>
> $$\sup_{A \in \mathcal{F}} \left|E(X_n1_{A}) - E(X1_{A})\right|\rightarrow 0.$$

Where, according to the book's notation, $X_n$ is a sequence of rv's, $A$ is an event and $\mathcal{F}$ the $\sigma$-algebra associated to $X_n$, while $1_A$ denotes the indicator function over the set $A$.

My guess is that since convergence in $L_1$ implies uniform integrability, one could use this fact to proceed, but I am completely stuck.

Comment: One direction: If $L^1$ convergence holds, then the triangle inequality gives
$$\sup_A |E(X_n 1_A) - E(X 1_A)| \le \sup_A E(|X_n-X| 1_A) \le E|X_n-X| \to 0.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"$\Rightarrow$": Use

$$|\mathbb{E}(X_n 1_A)-\mathbb{E}(X 1_A)|  \leq \mathbb{E}(|X_n-X|).$$

"$\Leftarrow$": Show

$$\mathbb{E}(|X_n-X|) = \mathbb{E}[(X_n-X) 1_{\{X_n-X \geq 0\}})]+ \mathbb{E}[(X-X_n) 1_{\{X_n-X<0\}}],$$

and conclude that

$$\mathbb{E}(|X_n-X|)  \leq 2 \sup_{A \in \mathcal{F}} |\mathbb{E}[(X_n-X) 1_A]|.$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? Thanks....

Comment: hi saz. It was me. The reason is because you gave a solution, not a hint. If this is not the forum practice i am happy to remove the downvote.

Comment: @Kolmo You are free to downvote the answer if you don't like it. However, it is pretty difficult to give a hint (which is not already a solution) for this particular problem.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. And actually I like the answer, quick and smart. But then why write "hints" (that is basically the reason for the down vote: I open the question; read it; then read the top of your answer: "hints". But then there was a full answer).

Comment: @Kolmo Better now?

Comment: Yes, there is no more the disconection.